# How can I ask about the "winner" of an ongoing match?

Tags: phrase-requests

Imagine that a match is being played now. The match has not ended yet. It is still played and each team is scoring some goals. Now, I would like to ask about the winner till now (at the middle of the match) ... How Can I express it?

Once, I said: "Who is the winner?" but the reply was: "The match has not ended yet". They got me wrong. How can I ask the question so that they understand me the correct way?

Comment: Who is winning so far?

Comment: This probably belongs on [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @J... How do you know that OP isn't a native speaker? Or does ELL allow native speakers to ask questions, which makes me to wonder what the different between the two sites is.

Comment: @J...Let's not make assumptions about who OP is or isn't unless he himself says it. Otherwise we'd have people voting to close questions just because they "thought" OP doesn't "look" like a native speaker.

Comment: @TheBitByte Neither ELL.SE nor EL&U.SE care who the contributor is and ELL.SE. It's about the question. It's not like ELL.SE is the one for non-native speakers and EL&U is the one for natives. It's about the kind of question. ELL.SE is more about basic usage, how can I say this, what does this mean, that kind of thing. The kind of thing that learners are more likely to need, but not necessarily. What's the difference between 'affect' and 'effect' is a question a native could definitely ask. It belongs on ELL.

Comment: This site tries to be more our "site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts", really looking at the hows and whys of the English language, where it comes from, older usage, that sort of thing. The kind of thing a learner could easily be interested in, but not the sort of thing you need or want to learn in an English as a second language class. That distinction is extremely messy, for example, we have a lot of single-word requests on EL&U and it's debatable whether that's at home on a site for "linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts"

Comment: I'm from Egypt. I'm not a native English speaker. But I think people like my question here that's why I got 5 likes.

Comment: @J... I didn't really ask for a guess, I asked *you* how sure you were of your own guess, and then said that not guessing at all would be a better solution.

Comment: "Who's winning/ahead/leading?"

Comment: I think the question is fine here. It's certainly not off-topic. It fits the chosen **Tags** (`phrase-requests` and `expression-requests`) quite well. It's just a hard thing to research... like searching for who is winning but not the winner... nothing useful comes up in Google.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> Who is in the lead?
>
> Who is ahead?
>
> Who is (currently) winning?

Comment: Or maybe "What's the score?".

Comment: It may be worth explaining the difference in tense between "winner" and "winning"; winner (in this context) is past-tense, therefore implying that the match has already finished, whereas the person who's "winning" is present tense which implies the match is currently ongoing

Comment: Joe hit the nail on the head there. "Who's winning?" is the most natural way for a native speaker to ask this question. @WS2 while that is a valid question, it is not the same question that was asked. I could reasonably answer you "two one" and you still wouldn't know who was winning

Comment: @DarrenH If it were cricket it would be possible to know the score without knowing who was winning.

Comment: @WS2 I understand that, such would be the case with most sports. My point is that the OP wanted to know who was winning, not what the score was. Your question, while being a valid question in it's own right, is not the same as the OPs question

Answer (score 3):

Who is the ***front runner***? This is applicable to any competitive situation where one wants to know who is ahead of the others (metaphorically speaking, one who is *running at the front* in a running race).

ODO:

> **[front runner](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/front_runner)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **1** The contestant that is leading in a race or other competition.
>   ‘the front runner for the presidential nomination’
>
> ‘This was the only race of the day where the front runner did not
>   control the race.’

Comment: While this does technically answer the question, it would not be deemed "normal usage". If you say this to someone at a football match they will raise an eyebrow to you and ask "Do you mean 'who's winning'?"